# MySQL Throwing Could not execute query. Command Out of Sync

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have some problem. My mysql is throwing some error :

Could not execute query.Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I have learn that the syntax itself perhaps conflict with the other function.

My case is, i have a page that getting result from database. And using while statement, it shows in the text box. Now, i want to update the values in the same page. Because some values are not text input, so it's not easy to get the values. I place another php function() inside the while() function.

here's the syntax:

while statement for rendering the textbox

```
     include '../functions/configuration.php';
        $query = "call sp_callViewTransc($ids)";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not execute query. " . mysql_error());
        **while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {**
        **<!-- WHILE FUNCTION IS GETTING RESULT FROM DB -->**
            ?>
            <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">General Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Computer Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">OS and Licenses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Remarks</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <p>Asset General Information. Some order goes here.</p>
                            <fieldset>
                                <!-- Text input-->
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Location</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input id="idms_location" name="idms_location" type="text" placeholder="location" class="input-xlarge" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row['idms_location']; ?>">
                                        <?php getLocation(); ?>
                                        **<!-- getLocation() function is another function in another file that getting dropdown values-->**
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Is there any php function to solve this code?

** update **

here's my second function in php that getting results for combobox

```
   function getLocation() {
     $query_location = "SELECT location, idms_location FROM ms_location";
     $location_list = mysql_query($query_location) or die("Could not execute query." .     mysql_error());
     echo "<select>";
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($location_list, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     echo("<option value='" . $row['idms_location'] . "'>" . $row['location'] . " </option>");
   }
     echo "</select>";
     mysql_close();
 }
```

Comment: It's likely this -> `<?php getLocation(); ?>`, are you executing another query from within this function?

Comment: yes @ohgodwhy , is there any tricks to make this work?

Comment: can you post the code for that function?

Comment: @stackErr, i have update this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by calling `mysql_query` to get data while you're looping over the results from another call.

At the moment you are calling `getLocation` for every result. So if you have 10 results you are making 10 calls to the database which will all return the same thing.

Instead, change the `getLocation` call to return a string and call it before the loop:

```
$location = getLocation();
```

Then in the loop you can do:

```
<?php echo $location ?>
```

Comment: okay jim, thanks, it working now, anyway, is there any ideas how to refactor my function so that, the <select> tag is placed in the main file? because, actually the <select> tag is place inside the function. So, i just echo the <option> vars.

Comment: Do you mean having `getLocation` just return the options? If you change it to do that you should be able to echo the select where you need it then call `getLocation`

Comment: yes, but the select options is showing empty results. so in my main php i wrote the syntax <select><?php echo getLocation ?></select> but it shows nothing in the options value.

Comment: So you are seeing `<select></select`? Double check `getLocation` to make sure it is returning a string.

Comment: if i create echo inside the function eg. echo "<select>" while (do loops) { echo <"option">.$row['result'];."</option>" } echo "</select>", it works.

Comment: Inside the function you should build up a string i.e. `$out = "";while(loops){$out .= "<option>"; return $out}`